# Using awk and df (disk free) to show only mount name and space used

Tags: bash, awk

What would be the correct CL sequence to execute a `df -h` and only print out the mount name and used space (percentage)? I'm trying to do a scripted report for our servers.

I tried

`df -h | awk '{print $1 $4}'`

which spits out

```
$df -h | awk '{print $1 $4}'
FilesystemAvail
/dev/sda164G
udev3.9G
tmpfs1.6G
none5.0M
none3.9G
none100M
/home/richard/.Private64G
```

How would you change this to add spacing? Am I selecting the right columns?

Comment: What's the problem with the command you have?

Comment: Hi KingsIndian, I added more information about. Specifically, how would I add spacing in awk?

Comment: Put a comma between `$1` and `$4`

Comment: Add a comma :) `df -h | awk '{print $1, $4}' `

Comment: I don't think you need the `-h` to get the percentage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
df -h | awk '{if ($1 != "Filesystem") print $1 " " $5}'
```

Or just

```
df -h | awk '{print $1 " " $5}'
```

if you want to keep the headers.

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1{print $1, $5}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues with your code are what input to process, and how to format the output.

As an example, this awk selects records that have a % symbol at the end of field five, and put a space between the two output fields.

```
 df -h | awk '$5 ~ /\%$/ {print $1 " " $5 }'
```

Everything else is just refining those two things.